# Magento2 - after upgrade to 2.2.5 - Element 'update': This element is not expected

Tags: layout, magento2.2, error, developer-mode

The strange about this is this error occurs only in **developer** mode

Looking at some layout files, I've seen a lot with this structure

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <update handle="XXX"/>
    ...
</layout>
```

Is that structure incorrect in 2.2.5? If that's the case... which could be the valid layout structure?

Maybe `<update handle=...>` should be only inside `<page>` sections, and not `<layout>`? Is that the problem?

Any tips to debug this?

Comment: No, it is same.  hope your using it for admin layout.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your comment kunj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. In our case, the problem was with some `<update handle="XXX"/>` placed **inside** a `<body>` section, while it should be at **same level** as `<body>`

What I can't understand, however, is why that same code was not throwing any error in production mode? Magento2 mysteries...

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to find where the offending xml is try out:

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamzero1/2c25dbcf1caec0ad9b55e7f6fd7972d8/raw/b19f6779625aa29122c0bc500ae213ab0b6bb212/nice_dom_error_message.patch
patch -p0 < nice_dom_error_message.patch
```

this should give you a nicer error message.
Full details here: https://gist.github.com/adamzero1/2c25dbcf1caec0ad9b55e7f6fd7972d8